Prove $\frac{1}{1+f(x)}$ is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.
This is a ISI PHD ENTRANCE sample question 2012.
The problem Given a non-negative measurable function over $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)}dx=1,
$$
then show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+f(x)}dx=\infty.$$
This question  comes with a hint: it says that first prove
$m\{x:f(x)<1\}=\infty$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.
How this hint will help me here?.
My efforts
I proceed by "reductio ad absurdum" in order to prove the property as suggested by the hint. Assume the property is not true: then $m\{x:f(x)\geq1\}=\infty$ which would imply
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)}dx=\infty
$$
which is clearly absurd. Hence the given hint is true.
Now we know that $m\{x:1+f(x)< 2\}=\infty$ and this implies $m\left\{x:\frac{1}{1+f(x)}>\frac{1}{2}\right\}=\infty$: but this in turn implies that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+f(x)}dx=\infty.
$$
What I am missing??

On that set of infinite measure, what can you say about the values of $1/(1+f)$?

I have no idea about it, since I am new to this subject

As an FYI: MSE is not a "do my (home)work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") are often in poor taste, downvoted, & closed; we expect users to actively put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. Also: this is helpful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 can help find past questions.

Hi! Do you know what Lebesgue measure is? Broadly speaking, it is a way to generalize the notion of length to well-behaved sets (and some not so well-behaved). The basic idea is that since $f(x) \geq 0$ at all $x$, there can only be so much of $f(x)$ that is over $1$ (because otherwise the integral would exceed $1$). Pretend that this is only true between $-1$ and $0$. Everywhere else, $f(x) < 1$—in particular, for $x > 0$. What can you say about $1+f(x)$ between $0$ and $\infty$? What about $\frac{1}{1+f(x)}$? What about its integral?

Given that program, please come back with a fuller attempt, or else specific questions about what you don't understand, rather than "I don't know how to proceed."

Even so, you could have added information such as (a) what you understand Lebesgue measure to be, (b) your attempt at proving the intermediate step suggested by the question, (c) some working out with specific $f(x)$ satisfying the constraints, etc. Some combination of the above would make this a more fleshed-out question.

Your solution seems to be correct -- apart from a little typo: ${x: 1+f(x)<2}=\left{x: \frac{1}{1+f(x)}>\frac 12\right}$.

This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1737516/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1653381/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1676938/42969 – all found with Approach0

Your question has changed completely, from "How this hint will help me here?" to a complete solution, followed by a  "What I am missing??", which (I guess) means "Is my solution correct?", so added the tag solution-verification. However, in this new situation, your question is "too broad": you are supposed to "identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so".
